# Multiple class confusion matrix explanation

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I'm training my own model with YoloV5 and after a test, I'm getting the following confusion matrix:

In the ground truth file (where there are the coordinates and the labels of all the bounding boxes) there are no "Car" and no "Bus".

[image]

What I understand from it is that the model is recognizing all the ground truth cars as bikers but, as I said before, in the video there are no cars.
Am I reading it in the wrong way?

Comment: are you sure the axes aren't labeled incorrectly? if you're using plot_confusion_matrix, I believe the standard is generally predicted on the x-axis, true on the y-axis. 

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py

Comment: @NiteshMenon the confusion matrix is entirely created by the YoloV5 script, I only gave in input the weights and the data to perform the prediction. So I assume the code is correct